# Referencing a field in a subform in ms access

Tags: ms-access

in ms access I have a form with a subform. In the subform in a field called "End_Date" in the main form I have a textbox that displays the end date if there is one and then "available" if there isn't any. I have been trying to use an iif statement for this. My problem however comes with trying to reference the field in the subform. Currently I am using the code "Forms![mainForm].[subform name].Form![End_Date]" I tried just using this statement to see if it would display the date at all, it will not. It displays "#name?". Microsoft online says this should successfully reference the field but I doesn't seem to work.

I need help, thank-you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have referenced a subform field in the following way before, but is your reference to do with a query or a form?

```
=Forms![mainForm].[subform name].Form.[End_Date]
```

N.B. I have had previous issues where i've tried to mix a string and a number value.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll attempt that tomorrow I'm in bed having given up for the night haha. Thank-you very much for the response though :) I'll let you know how it goes tomorrow :)